# Why pushviewController does nothing ? Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It is my function I linked to button. It doesn't push to another ViewController. It should work in following way : User clicks button, button creates alert, alert stays in current ViewController or pushes to different existing ViewController. No idea why it is not working - alert shows and nothing happens. Identifier is set and correct.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Aborting adding a routine scheme. Proceed?", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(.init(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(.init(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    // push to another VC
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WorkoutViewController")  as! WorkoutViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}))

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current ViewController isn't embed in `UINavigationController` so this line does nothing

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

... because `navigationController` is `nil`

If you want to just present ViewController use this

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Just. Works. Amazing, Thank You : )